# How to access attributes of ctypes Structure as if they were ctypes and not via the given wrapper?

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

This is inconsistent:

```
from ctypes import *

class S(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", POINTER(c_int)), ("y", c_int)]

o = S()
print o.x
print o.y
```

which returns

```
<__main__.LP_c_int object at 0x10d3d08c0>
0
```

So in one case, it returns a `ctypes` type, in the other case, it returns directly the value.

I have some more generic code where I always need to pass a `ctypes` type instance (which is also writeable, i.e. writing to it would mean to modify `o` in the above example). For `o.x`, this is ok. But not for `o.y`.

How can I get the `c_int` instance of `o.y`?

Comment: Please stop tagging your titles.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I think they are much more helpful/understandable this way. Also, tagging is slightly different. Tagging defines what this question is related to (nothing more, nothing less). By adding it in the title, I also define the topic of the question. Saying that something is the topic is more information than just saying that what it is related to.

Comment: Writing tags in titles is redundant. We already have a tagging system that is clear, concise, consistent and indexable. All you're doing by writing a pointless `Python:` at the start of your title is breaking SO's expectations (look in your titlebar), adding messy noise to your title, and winding me up. The "title" field is so named for a reason! Write the title, not some "topic". Nothing more, nothing less. SO is not a message board or chat forum. (And I fail to see how writing "Python" is "more information" than writing "Python".)

Comment: The title usually defines the topic of a question. Tagging only defines related topics of a question. So in almost all cases, it is really more helpful to explicitly state that. Even if the extra information is minimal and maybe obvious from the keywords, it is still more helpful. Without having "Python", "ctypes" and "structure" in the title, it is not anymore clear just from the title what the question is about. And this is definitely a bad thing. Also, it doesn't really hurt to have it there... Why even discuss about that? I really want to have the titles of my questions be that way...

Comment: It's not supposed to be clear "just from the title". The title is presented in consort with the tags.

Comment: Well, I'm always trying to balance between doing something as it is supposed to be done (btw., is this even really clearly stated? and where to draw the line? when to put 'Python' in the title and when not?) and how I think it would be the best. And in this case, I think it doesn't really hurt but only adds value. Maybe this discussion should be moved to 'meta'. But on the other side, I think this also doesn't really need any strict rules; they might even a bad thing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `_ctypes` source, it seems it doesn't do this clever automatic conversion for simple ctypes instances when they are wrapped.

So one (ugly) solution is this:

```
from ctypes import *

def WrapClass(c):
    class C(c): pass
    C.__name__ = "wrapped_" + c.__name__
    return C

class S(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", POINTER(c_int)), ("y", WrapClass(c_int))]

o = S()
print o.x
print o.y
print o.y.value
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I though it would be just a different **repr** method for the 'normal' types, but after some testing I think there is something definitely funky going on there. It really does make a difference if something is in or not a structure.

```
from ctypes import *

class S(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", POINTER(c_int)), ("y", c_int), ("z", c_float)]

o = S()

x = POINTER(c_int)
y = c_int(1)
z = c_float(2.2)

print("In structure: x:{}, y:{}, z:{}".format(o.x, o.y, o.z))
print("Out of structure: x:{}, y:{}, z:{}".format(x, y, z))
```

> In structure: x:<**main**.LP_c_long object at 0x000000000A090EC8>, y:0, z:0.0
>
> Out of structure: x:, y:c_long(1), z:c_float(2.200000047683716)

In particular, I think this should be considered buggy behavior:

```
o.x.contents = y #OK
o.x.contents = o.y #not OK!!
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   TypeError: expected c_long instead of int